# Filtering rows that ends with a certain value in Informatica mapping

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I will like to filter out rows which col1 ends with a certain value in my informatica mapping.

In SQL I will write it this way
Select * from table where col1 like ‘%- Test’.

Is it possible to implement this logic in the filter transformation of my informatica mapping?

I tried col1 like ‘%- Test’ in the filter condition and it does not work. Will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is possible. Depending on some conditions might be more or less simple. If your string has a fixed always the same length, just use [SUBSTR](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/data-integration/current-version/function-reference/functions/substr.html) function.

If the input length may vary and you need something closer to the '%' wildcard, it get's more difficult. Wildcard and LIKE function is not available. But you can calculate the total lenght of your input, substract 6 (for `- Test`) and then do the comparison, the resulting function would be like:

```
SUBSTR(in_portName, LENGTH(in_portName)-6, 6) = '%- Test'
```

Do let me know if you'd face any issues here.

Comment: You may want to remove the `%` character, as it's the wildcard for `LIKE`. If it's only at the end, this solution works. It can be more generic if the comparison uses an input port, for example `test_value`. `SUBSTR` also accepts negatives numbers for the start position to search from the end. The expression becomes `SUBSTR(in_portName, - LENGTH(test_value)) = test_value`.

Comment: valid point! updated to eliminate the wildcard character